# how i can perform group by based on range value of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to get desire output but failed many times. So here is my question to python expert.

I have DataFrame named df as given below.

df:-

```
VARIABLES   Estimate    LOWVAL  HIGHVAL
ppseg12      -0.1753       20       51
ppseg12      -0.1753       61       70
ppseg12      -0.1753       71       80
ppseg12      -0.1753       81       90
ppseg12       0.1153       91      100
```

i want to perform group by based on range of two columns(LOWVAL and HIGHVAL)

my desire output table:

df1 :-

```
VARIABLES   Estimate    LOWVAL  HIGHVAL
ppseg12      -0.1753       61       90   
ppseg12      -0.1753       20       51
ppseg12       0.1153       91       100
```

output logic for first row:-
its aggregating based on Variables and Estimate and there is no discontinuity in value of LOWVAL and HIGHVAL for example :- 61 LOWVAL -  70HIGHVAL.. 71LOWVAL -80HIGHVAL.. 81LOWVAL - 90HIGHVAL, SO it takes minimum of LOWVAL and maximum of HIGHVAL because they are in number series(like 61L 70H 71L 80H 81L 90H)

output logic for second row:-
As you can see it has same variable name and same estimate but it ranges of LOWVAL and HIGHVAL are not connecting or formed any series number. simply takes minimum and maximum of LOWVAL and HIGHVAL.

output logic for three row:-
because it has different estimate value, and separated by other groups. and simply takes minimum and maximum of LOWVAL and HIGHVAL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add two columns of differences and then add the difference column to the grouping and aggregate the minimum and maximum.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
VARIABLES   Estimate    LOWVAL  HIGHVAL
ppseg12      -0.1753       20       51
ppseg12      -0.1753       61       70
ppseg12      -0.1753       71       80
ppseg12      -0.1753       81       90
ppseg12       0.1153       91      100  
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['diff'] = df['LOWVAL'] - df['HIGHVAL']
df = df.groupby(['VARIABLES','Estimate','diff']).agg({'LOWVAL':min,'HIGHVAL':max}).reset_index()
df = df[['VARIABLES', 'Estimate', 'LOWVAL', 'HIGHVAL']]
df

VARIABLES   Estimate    LOWVAL  HIGHVAL
0   ppseg12 -0.1753 20  51
1   ppseg12 -0.1753 61  90
2   ppseg12 0.1153  91  100
```

Comment: this will not cover all condition ...for example make 31 instead of 51.. then this will fail. and output will loom like this pp12 -0.1753 20 90, ppseg12 0.11.53 91 100

Comment: I created the code based on the data you showed. On the other hand, you're missing the requirement to group them together.